# Downloading file from FTP

Tags: java, timer, ftp

I have an app which every 3 minutes download file from FTP server and then read it.
My problem is that this FTP transfer works only first time when app is launched, when timer runs this method next time, app crashes.
Here is how I call the method using timer

```
    Timer t2 = new Timer(180000, new ClockListener2());
    t2.start();
```

and then

```
   public class ClockListener2 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    downloadFtp();
    }
```

and now FTP transfer method

```
public void downloadFtp() {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        client.connect("192.168.1.102");
        client.login("anonymous", "");
        String filename = "text.txt";
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
        client.logout();
        client.disconnect();
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

did anyone met this problem before? What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: whats the output of e.printStackTrace()? can u put it here?

Comment: You should trying to disconnect and close the stream in the `finally` block to ensure that it is cleaned up with any exception occurs.  I'd also use a `SwingWorker` over a `javax.swing.Timer` or a `java.util.Timer` if it's not a Swing application

Comment: What I find out, app runs under windows without any problems, but under linux (Xubuntu) it crashes. On both machines there is the same version of java 1.7.0_25. Coulnd it be a problem in Java runtime instead of code?

Comment: Post the exception message. It might be caused by the application not being able to override the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect your device with ADB to view the logs printed by your device (see [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)).  If your app is crashed, you will see some FATAL exception trace (it's often very helpful) such as:

```
07-24 09:33:59.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ***.daifan.activity.***Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(***ListActivity.java:96)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:65)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:165)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:417)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:768)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3009)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```